# Parsing responseXML via AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to develop a small AJAX program.

XML I get from the server in responseXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<serverResponse><resultaat>1</resultaat></serverResponse>
```

If I try to retrieve the "resultaat" node and its content using this code :

```
var serverResponse = mailObject.responseXML;
var resultaatXML = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("resultaat");
alert(resultaatXML[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

Firefox alerts 1
And Internet Explorer alerts 'undefined'.

I'm really stuck at this. Can someone help?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Loading that XML into MSXML the code works fine. Try adding:-

```
alert(serverResponse.xml);
```

to see exactly what IE thinks is contained in the XML Document.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904443/mediawiki-ajax-ie-broken/1904528).  Basically, IE requires doesn't automatically parse the XML, you have to explicitly tell it to.  See [this article](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/04/easy-xml/) for more.